# How to get memory_limit to be recognized by Magento when doing readiness test

Tags: magento2, php-7, memory

I have had a terrible time getting extensions installed due to a readiness check. Magento fails to recognize that I have changed the php memory_limit figure.

This post applies but doesn't work. It seems like it would. I am stuck.
[setup-cron.ERROR: real memory limit 756M but 512M in log](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233192/setup-cron-error-real-memory-limit-756m-but-512m-in-log)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it through an ini_set within your script as shown below:

> ini_set('memory_limit', 2048MB);

This can be done in the following file temporarily

> app/etc/bootstrap.php

change:

> #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

to:

> #ini_set('display_errors', 1);
>   ini_set('memory_limit', 2048MB);

Comment: What script is this? Are you talking about index.php?

Comment: @macecase see my updated answer